# Hibernate second level cache and associations

Tags: hibernate, annotations, ehcache, second-level-cache

My class Movie has @OneToOne relationship with Director and a @ManyToMany relationship with Actor. All these classes (Movie, Director and Actor) classes are cached in read-only mode, and so are the collections.

I use Hibernate’s second level cache with ehCache.

The relationships are LAZY, so I have the following problem: if a Movie makes it to the second level cache without calling getDirector() or getActors(), we will get a LazyInitializationException if these methods are called subsequently without Session.merge(), and this is not an option for me.

I guess that my problem would be solved if I could hook to the event “put in cache” and call my lazy methods. Is there such a thing? I am reluctant writing custom infrastructure code, because second level caching is turned on/off depending on the application, etc.

Am I missing something else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the relationships are cached, what do you gain by having them LAZY fetched? Simply turn them to EAGER and your problem will be solved.